# How do I use [AVPlayer setRate:time:atHostTime:]

Tags: avfoundation

I am trying to use AVPlayer setRate:time:atHostTime: like this:

```
    CMTime tm = CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(seconds, 600);
    CMTime masterClock = CMClockGetTime (CMClockGetHostTimeClock());

    [pimpl->player setRate:1.0 time: tm atHostTime: masterClock];
```

But 95% of the time it crashes my program with an unhandled exception. Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before you can use `setRate:time:atHostTime:` you need to set `automaticallyWaitsToMinimizeStalling = NO`.

From the docs:

> For clients linked against iOS 10.0 and later or macOS 10.12 and later, 
>   invoking this method when automaticallyWaitsToMinimizeStalling is YES will 
>   raise an NSInvalidArgument exception.